# Excel calculation with variables

Tags: excel, formulas, vba

I have the following, lets say, problem:

I have two columns in excel with 5 rows each:

[image]

I want to know in which combination of 5 the result is 16.19, but if I've added in my calculation the amount in A1, then I have to exclude the amount in B1 and so on.

```
IE: =SUM(A5:A6,B2:B4) results 16.17
```

Comment: where are the variables mentioned in the title?

Comment: Well, I didn't know how to describe the issue, the variable is that when the amount in cell A1 is used, then I should exclude the amount in cell B1.

Comment: A variable is something very specific in programming. Think of a statement like `x=1`. In Excel variables are used in VBA, but some people also use the term for _named ranges_.

Comment: This question can be only answered if the rule describing which column is to be used in the sum. The computer cannot read your mind and know what to do. You have to tell it explicitly what to do.

Comment: I want to take 5 numbers from that table and see what's their sum, but if I took a number from column A then his pair from column B should be excluded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sumproduct as shown here:

[image]

The logic is straightforward. As an added benefit, it is easy to use the solver with this set up with the values in C2:C6 being the changing cells and constrained to be binary. You could set up as an objective function a formula which measures the difference between the target value and the expression in C8, and minimize this difference.

Comment: I don't think this is related, the question itself asks to know what's 5 digit combination to get the result 16.19 IE: =KnowDigits("A2:B6") 'Evaluation should say 'SUM(A1,A2,B1,B2,A4) equals 16.19 (just to state an example).

Comment: @Sgdva I noticed that. I took `16.19` as the intended target value and the displayed choice as a failure to reach that target. This is why I mentioned the solver. In this case it appears to be the closest you can get to `16.19`.